# Restrict the Type of files to be upload in DAM under a specific Path in AEM 6.3

Tags: aem, dam

I want to restrict the types of files to be uploaded under a path. For Ex, /content/dam/test should only upload Pdf's file under it.
I try to add a property mimeTypes under this node :

**/libs/dam/gui/content/assets/jcr:content/actions/secondary/create/items/fileupload**

but it puts the restrictions over the complete dam folder.

Any Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

2 options that I can think of:

- Do it in JS. Add a listener and write custom logic there.
- Add a custom step in upload asset workflow and perform all your logic
  there.